# How do I calculate how many hashes I generate per second?

Tags: c#, multithreading, hash

I have a function which generates hashes from a string:
`string GenerateHash(string plainText);`
I generate as many hashes as possible with 4 threads.

How do I calculate how many hashes (or megahashes) I generate per second?

Comment: Are you looking for number of hashes per thread or overall number of hashes in total.

Comment: Use a shared counter variable.

Comment: Why the negative rep?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem breaks down nicely into 3 separate tasks

1. Sharing a single count variable across threads
2. Benchmarking thread completion time
3. Calculating hashes p/sec

**Sharing a single count variable across threads**

```
public static class GlobalCounter
{
    public static int Value { get; private set; }

    public static void Increment()
    {
        Value = GetNextValue(Value);
    }

    private static int GetNextValue(int curValue)
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref curValue);
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        Value = 0;
    }
}
```

Before you spin off the threads call `GlobalCounter.Reset` and then in each thread (after each successful hash) you would call `GlobalCounter.Increment` - using `Interlocked.X` performs atomic operations of `Value` in a thread-safe manner, it's also much faster than `lock`.

**Benchmarking thread completion time**

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.ForEach(someCollection, someValue => 
{
    // generate hash
    GlobalCounter.Increment();
});
sw.Stop();
```

`Parallel.ForEach` will block until *all* threads have finished

**Calculating hashes per second**

```
...
sw.Stop();
var hashesPerSecond = GlobalCounter.Value / sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable to count the number of hashes generated and divide it accordingly all x seconds using a timer.

Its probably most performant if you have a counter for each thread and the timer just reads all the counters. Then you do not have as much locking.

Comment: Unless the 'parent' thread collects all the hashes from each thread, in which case it can simply count them once received.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to more accurately measure time passing. You can start your stopwatch, generate your hashes, then stop the stopwatch. Then you should have a count of the hashes and a total time it took to generate, which you need to calculate the per-second rate.